# Infineon XMC4400 CAN message object and LIST register

Tags: embedded, microcontroller, can-bus

I am using Infineon XMC4400 Controller and I am converting Basic CAN functionality to Full CAN functionality.
I am facing difficulty in understanding Message Object allocation with LIST register-
As per my knowledge-

- XMC4400 supports 64 Message object and each MO must be allocated to
  one of the LIST register.
- There are 8 LIST registers in MultiCAN module
- Using PANCTR we can update/modify/remove the Message object to/from
  the LIST

(Please correct me if I am wrong.)

So my question is **Can we allocate all 64 MOs to single LIST register or is there is any limitation?** 
I am not finding the clear explanation in reference Manual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can assign all available object to one list. Except List0, because List0 contains unallocated objects.

Refer the PANCNTR register and update the index properly so u can assign the object to particular list.